# Help! About 500 errors a day from ScriptResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I get more than 500 exceptions daily from ScriptResource.axd (ASP.NET website).
It seems to comming from the Ajax Update Panel but I am not sure. 
Anyway, is it possible to fix these exceptions?

Comment: Yes... but you're going to need to give us a bit more information.

Comment: Could there be a client somewhere that has lost their session but is still trying to send a request to the server that may explain this?

Comment: As Tom says: can you give us some more info on the errors you are getting? Where are you seeing the errors, what exceptions are being reported, what's the user agent, etc. On top of that have you used something Firebug or IE8's dev tools to see what responses you're getting back from the ScriptResource calls on the page?

Answer (score 3):

There is one simple way, that might mean quite a lot of work depending on how far you've already gotten in your developement process, but will give you enough benefits for it to be worth the effort anyway: **don't use the ASP.Net UpdatePanel**.

Instead, take a look at [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) with it's extensive [ajax support](http://docs.jquery.com/ajax). It will help you increase control over what you do, it will help you speed your site up (by a lot) and it will help you become better at client-side scripting.

Comment: I never used to appreciate everyone responding with "use jQuery" every time a question involved javascript, even though I try not to use UpdatePanels because of all their limitations - however having just spent this last week really getting to grips with jQuery, I have to say it really does make your life easier :)